# Unable to hide the content when scrolling down in mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to scoll down a content in a mobile layout but I'm not able to hide the content under the header:

[image]

And what I want is:

[image]

The code I have for now is:
HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <h1>Website Example</h1>
            </header>

            <div id="content">
                <figure class="home-image">
                    <img class="centered" src="images/home-image.jpg" />
                </figure>

                <article>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                </article>
            </div><!-- end content -->

        </div><!-- end wrapper -->
    </div><!-- end container -->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    /* Prevents iPhone from resizing in landscape mode */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;        
}

* { 
    /* Apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* BODY */
body {
    font-size: 16px;                        /* Default size based on mobile */
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #1f253d;
}


/* CONTAINER */
#container {
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 600px;
}

/* CONTAINER */
#wrapper {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 10px auto;
}

/* HEADER */
header {
    background-color: #394264;
    position: fixed;
    width: 95%;
    opacity: .9;
}

header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    opacity: .9;
    line-height: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: .8em;
}


/* CONTENT */
#content {
    width: 100%;   
    margin: auto;
}

#content article {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #394264;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    padding: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1F253D;
}

/* IMAGES */
figure {
    width: 100%;
}

figure img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #394264;
}

figure img.centered {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Any idea how I can hide the content under the header?

Also the scroll is not visible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to keep your HTML free, you've been applying min-width and max-widths to container, please don't do that, you are restricting the html. Just keep it simple.

I guess this is what you're toking about. Please check the code below:

Here's the **UPDATED** [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cq7K2/5/)

**CSS**

```
    html {
    /* Prevents iPhone from resizing in landscape mode */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;        
}

* { 
    /* Apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    text-decoration: none;
    margin:0;padding:0;
}


/* BODY */
body {
    font-size: 16px;                        /* Default size based on mobile */
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #1f253d;
    position:relative;    
}

/* CONTAINER */
#wrapper {position:absolute;}

/* HEADER */
header {
    background-color: #394264;
    position: fixed;
    top:20px;
    width:100%;
    opacity: .9;
}

header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    opacity: .9;
    line-height: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: .8em;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar{display: none;}

/* CONTENT */
#content{height:300px;overflow-x:hidden;position:relative;top:95px;}
#content article {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background: #394264;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    padding: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1F253D;
}

/* IMAGES */
figure {
    width: 100%;
}

figure img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #394264;
}

figure img.centered {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I use min-width and max-with because it's a responsive layout. Your solution forces the header to be at top 0 and I don't want this, I want to keep the margin but I don't want the content to pass over it.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, if it's a responsive design, don't use max-width or min-width. And what do you exactly want..?? Do you want the the header to be fixed or not?

Comment: I want the header fixed with a margin from the top, where the content (that includes the image) goes under

Comment: No because the image is visible between Website Example and the top of the visible area

Comment: How do you pass the content under the header (in your code)?

Comment: I assigned position:relative to the body, and position absolute for the wrapper and I positioned your header to be fixed at 20px from top. So the header is going to stay there at 20px. Now the content part, I assigned position:relative to  #content. After that I positioned it to be 95px from top, now this is going to start from 95px, then I applied a certain height(to mark the visible area to be) for the content. Applied overflow-x to be hidden, so as to have a vertical-scroll.

In short, I added css in such a way so that everything should stay in place except for the content section.

Comment: Great! And can I extend your solution to be responsive in the height of the content?

Comment: To make it responsive, calculate the height of window and assign it to the height of container. I use jquery $(window).height(); function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this to the header in css

```
top: 0;
```

The header css would be this:

```
header {
    background-color: #394264;
    position: fixed;
    width: 95%;
    opacity: .9;
    top: 0;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyZC5/

This happens because the position: fixed automatically sets the element to the center, so you have to define where you want to place the element, in this case at the top of the page, that's why the top: 0;

Comment: Hi thanks but I don't want to header at top 0, I want a margin around it, and the content to pass under.

Comment: Can't you see the truck's image in the top of the picture? and the difference to the second one?